# Why is my code running slower after trying Goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

I decided to try figuring out Goroutines and channels. I made a function that takes a list and adds 10 to every element. I then made another function that attempts to incorporate channels and goroutines. When I timed the code it ran much slower. I tried doing some research but was unable to figure anything out.

Here is my code with channels:

```
package main

import ("fmt"
        "time")

func addTen(channel chan int) {
    channel <- 10 + <-channel
}

func listPlusTen(list []int) []int {
    channel := make(chan int)
    for i:= 0; i < len(list); i++ {
        go addTen(channel)
        channel <- list[i]
        list[i] = <-channel
    }
    return list
}

func main(){
    var size int
    list := make([]int, 0)
    fmt.Print("Enter the list size: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &size)

    for i:=0; i <= size; i++ {
        list = append(list, i)
    }
    start := time.Now()
    list = listPlusTen(list)
    end := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(end.Sub(start)) 
}
```

Comment: Why would the code be made faster by doing more work?

Comment: Although you are using goroutines you are still doing the additions in a serial manner. You iterate over the list and send the element thought the channel then you wait to get the element back from the channel before going to the next one. So you get no parallalization and you add the overhead of sending things through channels.

Comment: Using goroutines usually only make sense when they do IO tasks or database queries, as they are things with many (small) wait times in between. Your code is neither of these and its speed is only dependent on the processor (not disk, network etc). Thus, you're running more instructions to do the same work, which in turn is slower

Comment: @xarantolus that's not true. goroutines makes sense whenever concurrency makes sense, not necessarily related to i/o.

Comment: @xarantolus that's completely false. Goroutines are a concurrency mechanism which have uses well beyond I/O.

Comment: To expand on what Carlos said and maybe give you a better feeling about _parallelization…_ Suppose you have a slice of one million elements and have to run a calculation on _each_ of them, and it takes, say five seconds on a slinge CPU core. Let's further assume the calculations are all independent from each other. Now you could spawn as much coroutines as you have CPU cores, N, and make each process every Nth element—that is, moving in strides of width N. _That_ would give you almost ×N speedup for real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a lot of synchronization overhead to the baseline algorithm. You have len(list) goroutines, all waiting to read from a common channel. When you write to the channel, the scheduler picks one of those goroutines, and that goroutines adds 10, and writes to the channel, which enables the main goroutine again. It is hard to speculate without really measuring it, but if you move the goroutine creation outside the for-loop, then you will have only one goroutine, reducing the scheduler overhead. However, in any comparison to the baseline algorithm this will be slower, because each operation involves two synchronizations and two context switches, which take more that the algorithm itself.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar experience with go routines where I was making 20 http requests using the same function.

calling the function in a simple loop was much faster than using wait groups